# WCF - Wondering about Request Queueing

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a quick simply question about requests in WCF. Does WCF automatically queue requests to a service(the service being a singleton) when multiple users request the same process, ie lets say I have a function that takes a while to complete, and two users make a call to this function, does WCF automatically queue the requests so that when the first request is finished it then starts processing the next?

~Just Wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service behavior attribute on the contract defines how sessions, instances and concurrency are handled.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx for more details.

Basically you can configure it (1) handle one request at a time or (2) multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: Ok, so i get if you set it to instances it wont matter but if its set to singleton, does wcf automatically handle the queuing?

Comment: Yes, WCF will handle the queueing.