# Synchronous file download using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, download, wcf-rest

I have a WCF REST based service which downloads and stores video files in the web server machine. The maximum size of video files is around 1MB and the download is asynchronous at present.

Is it possible to use synchronous download and will a timeout occur if large number or requests are submitted almost simultaneously? If so is there a mechanism to handle the situation?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up your service to act as a singleton.  WCF will handle the queueing of multiple calls.  A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195009/wcf-wondering-about-request-queueing), and may be of help.